# Ouvrage de référence en typographie ou publication de l’Imprimerie Nationale

Tags: usage, typographie

Je souhaite savoir s’il existe un ouvrage de référence qui fait foi parmi les typographes des usages en langue française. Je m’attends un peu à ce que ce soit une quelconque publication de l’Imprimerie Nationale par exemple ou d’une autre institution car je crois avoir entendu parler d’un tel document sans parvenir à me remémorer son nom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, il existe bien un tel livre : [Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale](http://www.amazon.fr/Lexique-r%C3%A8gles-typographiques-lImprimerie-Nationale/dp/2743304820).

Comment: Merci, c’était bien ce que je cherchais :)